# APPIUM and running adb to detect connected devices

Tags: java, node.js, windows, appium

having issues with connected devices. I have a Samsung Galaxy 5  SAMSUNGSM-G900V ANDROID version 5. Device is in Debug mode with USB Debugging turned on.  When I run:

executing cmd: C:\Users\XXXXX\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe devices
info: [debug] 0 device(s) connected

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can this be due to ANDROID 5.0 USB does not work with USB 3.0? I read that somewhere?

Comment: If you are using windows, you should install pdanet it helps system to connect devices using usb

Comment: Moved to Samsung Galaxy 8 with no luck. I've learned that you can test the connection via  Chrome browser and using the URL:  chrome://inspect/#devices  that does not see my device.  I've also read you need to install the Intel Android USB driver.

Comment: https://software.intel.com/protected-download/385047/494732

Comment: Now I'm trying thru the SDK   http://visualgdb.com/KB/usbdebug-manual/

Comment: Following the SDK Driver install, this worked to connect the device. The Chrome: chrome://inspect/#devices seems to have issues (That is what I've read.)

Answer (score 0):

Following the SDK Driver install, this worked to connect the device. The Chrome: chrome://inspect/#devices seems to have issues (That is what I've read.)

Once I tried to run my automation thru Appium, the device showed up in Chrome inspector, and in the Android SDK

Comment: This is a good read:  https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/6858  Don't use the Windows 1.4.16 version of Appium (Windows U/I) Use 1.6 the command line version.  There is a beta version that might work:  https://github.com/appium/appium-desktop/releases